# Lazarus IDE: Master-Detail database tables and data-aware components

Tags: database, one-to-many, master-detail, lazarus

In Lazarus (using version 1.6) I would like to create a form using data-aware components able to display and edit **master-detail (one-to-many) relationship between two or more tables in a database**. I'd like to know **if it's possible to use built-in ready-made IDE GUI components for such task, and how to do it, or if it requires some extra code**.

Suppose, just for example, that there are two database tables: publishing houses and books, each with it's own primary key field, but the books table does not contain cross-reference data from the beginning: users should be able to select a book and then decide to which publishing house it belongs to, using a DBComboBox, and the form will automatically update the books table inserting the publishing house ID in the appropriate foreign key field in books table. More: users shoud be able to create publishing houses and books and connect them at run-time.

In other words I need to build a GUI editing tool able to associate "items" of a table with their "categories" of another table in a one-to-many relationship, and I'd like to know if it's possible to use ready-made Lazarus data-aware controls, and how to use them, or if it requires some extra-coding.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not master detail, that is simply TDBComboBox with the lookup key and value properties properly configured. But that is still one to one (one book belongs to one publishing house).

I emulated categories by simply having two small grids with their own queries. One lists the categories for this item, one the ones not for that item, and then two arrows between them (that do nothing more than get the primary key of the category and store or delete that from the cross-table)